# Element.getElementById() not working

Tags: javascript, svg, getelementbyid

Basically, I'm unable to get the element `text` from following SVG:

```js
panel =  document.getElementById("panel");
g = panel.getElementById("gtext");
t = g.getElementById("text");

t.textContent = "hello";
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="80" id="panel">    
    <g id="gtext" transform="translate(0,48) scale(1 1)">
        <text id="text">
           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </text>    
    </g>
</svg>
```

The inspector says the group `gtext` has no `getElementById` function

My goal is to change the content of `text`.

Here is [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/mrcasty/pen/ZeJjjE):

Comment: Thanks for the edit!
Next time I'll try to use the Code Snippet

Answer (score 22):

From [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

> Unlike some other similar methods, `getElementById` is only available as a method of the global `document` object, and not available as a method on all element objects in the DOM. Because ID values must be unique throughout the entire document, there is no need for "local" versions of the function.

That's why when you try to call `getElementById` as a function of some element in DOM it throws an error in console.

As `id`s of DOM elements should be unique inside a single document, you can use:

```
t = document.getElementById("text");
```

**Working Example:**

```js
t = document.getElementById("text");

t.textContent = "hello";
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="80" id="panel">    
    <g id="gtext" transform="translate(0,48) scale(1 1)">
        <text id="text">
           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </text>    
    </g>
</svg>
```

---

Alternatively you can use `.querySelector()`. This is available as a method of global `document` object as well as on all element objects in DOM.

You can use the following variant:

```
panel =  document.querySelector("#panel");
g = panel.querySelector("#gtext");
t = g.querySelector("#text");

t.textContent = "hello";
```

**Working Example:**

```js
panel =  document.querySelector("#panel");
g = panel.querySelector("#gtext");
t = g.querySelector("#text");

t.textContent = "hello";
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="80" id="panel">    
    <g id="gtext" transform="translate(0,48) scale(1 1)">
        <text id="text">
           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </text>    
    </g>
</svg>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @PaulLeBeau for this:

`.getElementById()` is also available as a method of `SVGSVGElement`. We can access it if we have a reference to an SVG element inside DOM. For example:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('my-svg');
var t = svg.getElementById("text");
```

However, this method is not available on any element other than `SVG` inside DOM.

**Working Example:**

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('my-svg');
var t = svg.getElementById("text");

t.textContent = 'hello';
```

```html
<svg id="my-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="80" height="80" id="panel">    
    <g id="gtext" transform="translate(0,48) scale(1 1)">
        <text id="text">
           XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </text>    
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: A slight correction.. `getElementById()` is also available on `SVGSVGElement`, which is the DOM class for `<svg>`.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yes, you are right but it is candidate recommended phase in per [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement) and may not have good browser support.

Comment: Actually no. SVG2 is in CR status, but `getElementById()` is present in SVG 1.1 which reached Recommendation status in 2003.  Browser support is not a problem.

Comment: I have cloned <svg> elements nested inside another <svg>'s. Would it be enough if the id's are unique along each nested <svg> ?

Comment: @javanoob No, they must be unique across the whole document.

Comment: Important information that I took from this is that "ids of DOM elements should be unique inside a single document". I had some code that was dynamically generating IDs, but a bug meant that they were not all unique. Once I fixed that, the issue was resolved for me

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById()` is not a function that is available for group elements.  You either need to use `document.getElementById()` or you can call it from an `<svg>` element.

```
var mysvg = getElementById("mysvg");
var t = mysvg.getElementById("text");
```

Or if you already had a reference to the group element, you could use the `ownerSVGElement` property to get the group's ancestor SVG element. Then call `getElementById()` from there.

```
g = panel.getElementById("gtext");
...
mysvg = g.ownerSVGElement;
t = mysvg.getElementById("text");
```