# JavaScript AJAX: pick up two objects in response

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML page with *two* divs:

```html
<div id = "first_div">some initial stuff here</div>
<div id = "second_div">another stuff here</div>
```

and I have a JavaScript AJAX function that sends a request. The response returns a page with *two* objects, e.g. paragraphs:

```html
<p id = "first_paragraph">contents of the first paragraph</p>
<p id = "second_paragraph">contents of the second paragraph</p>
```

How can I adjust my script to achieve that the *first_paragraph* from the response is inserted into the *first_div*, and the *second_paragraph* from the response is inserted into the *second_div*?

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
  {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById("first_div").innerHTML = //put here the first paragraph from the response;
      document.getElementById("second_div").innerHTML = //put here the second paragraph from the response
    }
};
```

Comment: It will be hard to help you when we don't know what the response looks like. You somehow need to parse the `xhttp.responseText` and split the text somewhere. PS, recommend you to try out the fetch api instead of XMLHttpRequest

Comment: How the response looks like? Is it JSON?

Comment: The response is as I described above: just a plain text, no JSON.

Comment: You can use `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. It would be simpler.

Comment: I'm a beginner so I followed AJAX tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp .Could you pls expand your answer? They don't mention `fetch` on that website. What's the benefit compared to `XMLHttpRequest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your response is plaint text:

```html
<p id = "first_paragraph">contents of the first paragraph</p>
<p id = "second_paragraph">contents of the second paragraph</p>
```

you can parse your response as a DOM element and assign the content to the element you want later.

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    //declare a element to store the response and parse as a DOM element.
    var el = document.createElement("html");
    el.innerHTML = this.responseText;

    var fp = el.querySelector("#first_paragraph");
    var sp = el.querySelector("#second_paragraph");

    document.getElementById("first_div").appendChild(fp); //put here the first paragraph from the response;
    document.getElementById("second_div").appendChild(sp); //put here the second paragraph from the response
  }
};
```

**Update**:
Change `getElementById` to `querySelector`

From:

```js
var fp = el.getElementById("first_paragraph");
var sp = el.getElementById("second_paragraph");
```

to

```js
var fp = el.querySelector("#first_paragraph");
var sp = el.querySelector("#second_paragraph");
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect as it consumes the response that I mentioned. However, I'm getting an error: ```el.getElementById is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange```. It feels to me that the variable `el` doesn't have that method?

Comment: following https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802781/2743931 the `getEelementById` method can only be called on the global `document`. For my custom element `el` I can use ```var fp = el.querySelector("first_paragraph");
    var sp = el.querySelector("second_paragraph");``` - which worked. But thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment (and also recommended by @Endless), you can use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

In the following examples, I will get responses from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com), since I don't know the source you're using.

**Example #1** (get text):

```js
const fetchData = async() => (await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')).text();

fetchData()
  .then(data => {
    first_div.innerHTML = data;
    second_div.innerHTML = data;
  });
```

```html
<div id="first_div">some initial stuff here</div>
<div id="second_div">another stuff here</div>
```

**Example #2** (get JSON):

```js
const fetchData = async() => (await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')).json();

fetchData()
  .then(data => {
    first_div.innerHTML = data.id;
    second_div.innerHTML = data.title;
  });
```

```html
<div id="first_div">some initial stuff here</div>
<div id="second_div">another stuff here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This indeed looks more simple and efficient. I'll practice and consider replacing my code.

Comment: @user2743931 You're welcome. Please, consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to replace my code by your solution. I'm upvoting as your answer provides the best solution but the accepted answer is exactly answering the question without having to modify the code structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using `XMLHttpRequest`if you want to use `$.ajax()`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "//page url here",
    method: "GET"
}).done((response) => {
    document.getElementById("first_div").innerHTML = response.para1,
    document.getElementById("second_div").innerHTML = response.para2
});
```

Provided the server returns an object like this

```
{
    para1: "This is paragraph 1 ...",
    para2: "This is paragraph 2 ..."
}
```

**P.S: To use ajax you need to add the following to your HTML Page**
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you. Over time I'll try to improve the functions. I know there is a simpler AJAX call than mine but I'm just a beginner. The server returns a plain text response.